# How to get correct date in Jasper Parameters using URL

Tags: url, jasper-reports, url-routing, jasperserver

I am creating an URL below is sample URL:

```
http://localhost:9090/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&ndefined=&standAlone=true&start_date=01-01-2011&end_date=31-12-2011 ......
```

here I am passing a start_date = 01-01-2011 and end_date = 31-12-2011, but I am not getting dates as given in the URL. Instead I am getting start_date as 0001-11-30 and end_date as 0030-11-01.

is there any way to get the proper dates in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Your date needs to be in this format: `yyyyMMddHHmmss`

That's configurable. It's set in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="hyperlinkDateParameterFormatter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.HyperlinkDateParameterFormatter">
  <property name="pattern" value="yyyyMMddHHmmss"/>
</bean>
```

In general I recommend modifying your url and conforming to the default format. But in principle you could modify appContext and continue to use your format.

Comment: I tried this:

   created_at_end=20120801000000

but I get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

change the parameter format and you should be good to go e.g.  date_format($P{start_date},'%m-%d-%Y')

Comment: Done the same but its giving same result